# Dynamic Task Reminder Alert

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, alert

I have to write code for Web Based application, in this I have a task reminder panel On Home Page.Where Task List will be shown and also a Add Button where user can add new task reminder.Add Reminder Button is working and Task Reminder is Successfully going in Database.When user logged in the Home page opened and have to show the Alert Message Box when time will come. How I can do. Please Any Example Help.

Here Is my Task Reminder Model:

```
public Class TaskRemider 
{
   public int TaskID { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Task name is Required")]
   public string Task { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Task date is Required")]
   public DateTime? TaskDate { get; set; }

   public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
   public int AddedBy { get; set; }
   public string strAddedBy { get; set; }
   public DateTime? AddedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please clarify this small thing: You want to show the user how much time left until the date or you want to alert user when an specific date has come?

Comment: i want to show that how much time left until date and specific date has come also. have to cover both scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web application the connection from server and client is lost after the page loads and you can't send anything to your client.

Although there is a method of doing it in server code (called `Signal R`) but, your scenario is better handled in client side using JavaScript code.

To do that you can put this in your page:

```
<script>
    var date = @TaskDate
    var milliseconds = @(TaskDate - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(milliseconds > 0){
            alert('Your task will be due on ' + str(date));
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                alert('Time has come');
                //Or any other thing you might want to do
            }, milliseconds);
        }
        else{
            alert('The time has already come');
        }
    }
</script>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: but i have list of task reminders. and have to check i lsit.

Comment: Yes what I have shown you is just an example. You can do whatever you want using JavaScript and jQuery. Plus you have no choice but to use this or the `Signal R` which is way harder to implement and manage and is for more important tasks like online real-time games

Comment: i know the way from jquery and from client side. i want to know  if anything from server side dynamically?

Comment: Search for Signal R

Comment: please mention if any question available here?

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: Accept your answer for client side scripting.